# Heroku deploy errors python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully

Tags: python, django, web, heroku, deployment

I have a few problems and errors deploying heroku website.

I have used django to create the website and want to deploy the website that I have gotten so far.

I have all of the required packages installed in my local and in my virtual environment as well.

However, When I try deploying the website, I get the following errors:

```
× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
         │ exit code: 1
         ╰─> [83 lines of output]
             /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
             !!
             
                     ********************************************************************************
                     Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
                     If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.

!!
               dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
               error: subprocess-exited-with-error
             
               × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
               │ exit code: 1
               ╰─> [17 lines of output]
                   Traceback (most recent call last):
                     File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
                     File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
                     File "/tmp/pip-wheel-2xd7j5kf/distribute_1efc1e9757504aed986ff8beb549bcab/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
                       from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
                     File "/tmp/pip-wheel-2xd7j5kf/distribute_1efc1e9757504aed986ff8beb549bcab/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
                       from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
                     File "/tmp/pip-wheel-2xd7j5kf/distribute_1efc1e9757504aed986ff8beb549bcab/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
                       from setuptools.command.install import install
                     File "/tmp/pip-wheel-2xd7j5kf/distribute_1efc1e9757504aed986ff8beb549bcab/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
                       from setuptools.command import install_scripts
                     File "/tmp/pip-wheel-2xd7j5kf/distribute_1efc1e9757504aed986ff8beb549bcab/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
                       from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
                     File "/tmp/pip-wheel-2xd7j5kf/distribute_1efc1e9757504aed986ff8beb549bcab/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
                       register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
                   [end of output]
             
               note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
             error: metadata-generation-failed
             
             × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
             ╰─> See above for output.
             
             note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
             hint: See above for details.
             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 96, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
                 subprocess.check_call(cmd)
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
                 raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
             subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/app/.heroku/python/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpaaqkndf4', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
             
             The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
               File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
               File "/tmp/pip-install-3p1f5saj/dotenv_646ba309b67d4732bcfce4160ecc8efb/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
                 setup(name='dotenv',
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 106, in setup
                 _install_setup_requires(attrs)
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 79, in _install_setup_requires
                 _fetch_build_eggs(dist)
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 84, in _fetch_build_eggs
                 dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 907, in fetch_build_eggs
                 return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
                 resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
                 dist = self._resolve_dist(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 865, in _resolve_dist
                 dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in best_match
                 return self.obtain(req, installer)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1147, in obtain
                 return installer(requirement)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 98, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
                 raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
             distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/app/.heroku/python/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpaaqkndf4', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
             [end of output]
         
         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
       error: metadata-generation-failed
       
       × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
       ╰─> See above for output.
```

I have no idea what the errors mean and I have tried the pep517, which did not work.
Will be so so so much appreciated if this is solved out.

Comment: The error you are facing is due to the version conflict that is you have different python version on your Heroku server and on your local machine

Answer (score 0):

The error is most probably because of version conflict that is different python version on your local machine and different version on the Heroku. So to solve this you can specify a python version by creating- **runtime.txt**  in your app directory and in that enter this text

```
python-3.9.*
```

and save. Change 3.9 to your python version. Then push it to your git, then it should work fine
For more info you can refer to there official site - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes